# sql query with left joins and preventing null results (datatables)

Tags: php, mysql, sql, join

I am using datatables with a modified ssp.class.php to allow for joins and other custom features. In the example below I only want to return results from `computers` for the first x rows sorted by their id.  Because of this, I list `computers` with my conditions first then LEFT JOIN `users` followed by `logs` (the information I am after).

It works great, BUT because of the left joins I have empty results.  For instance, while my result set only contains `logs` from the correct `computers`... if `logs` has no rows for a particular user/computer combination I have a row with empty `log` data, but with user/computer data which serves me no purpose.

Is my only option to include a WHERE condition to prevent null values in the `logs` join... `WHERE logs.user_id != ''` or is there some other logic I can do in the select that I am missing?

```
SELECT (*see note)
FROM
    ( SELECT account_id, computer_id, computer_name
        FROM computers
        ORDER BY computer_id ASC LIMIT 0, ".$_SESSION['user']['licenses']."
    ) as c
    LEFT JOIN users
        on users.computer_id = c.computer_id
    LEFT JOIN logs
        on logs.user_id = users.user_id
```

Comment: just add a where condition at the end `where logs.user_id IS NOT NULL`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use just JOIN for the table logs.

Comment: I recommend to always use the 'full name' (`INNER JOIN` in this case) of the join, instead of just placing `JOIN`. This improves readability.

Comment: That works... I guess I had a different understanding of its meaning.  So, to be clear... if I INNER JOIN `logs` is it joining to just `users` or the set (`c` with LEFT JOIN `users`)?

Answer (score 0):

You put a LIMIT in the Derived Table accessing the `computers` table returning `n`rows. When an Inner Join or a final WHERE-condition filters some rows you will get less than `n`rows.

If this is not ok for you and you always want `n`rows, the only way is to move the LIMIT after doing Inner Joins:

```
SELECT (*see note)
FROM computers as c
    JOIN users
        on users.computer_id = c.computer_id
    JOIN logs
        on logs.user_id = users.user_id
ORDER BY computer_id ASC LIMIT 0, ".$_SESSION['user']['licenses']."
```

But this will probably be [much] slower...